# TDD Test Structure Question

Tags: unit-testing, tdd, integration-testing

So say I'm doing TDD and I write a test like this:

```
public void testDeposit()
{
    Bank b = new Bank();
    b.deposit(100);
    AssertEquals(100, b.balance);
}
```

Then I go and make the test pass, move on to the next one. Say I do this for a few in a row and get deposits, withdrawals, and amortization all working.

Then say I want to write a test that tests someone creating an account and doing a combination of everything. Isn't this technically an integration test, not a unit test? If it is, does this fit into TDD, or is TDD supposed to only consist of unit tests.

Mainly I'm asking because, if this test breaks, most likely one of the other tests should break, and if they don't, I probably just haven't tested them with the right amount of scenarios. So should I have integration tests in the same domain as unit tests when it comes to TDD, or should these be written in another class/file somewhere else and run separately?

Comment: Another way to skin it.. would be TDD => unit tests => one behavior for one object at a time. ATDD => scenario tests => one user scenario at a time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think high level tests can certainly have a place as part of a TDD workflow. For example testing "outside in" can be a very effective way to define new features. Start with some UI level acceptance test for the new feature, write integration tests for the components which will need to exist to provide that feature, and write unit tests to drive the implementation of each component.

I think you should keep the distinction between your types of tests clear and not mix them together but it can make sense to include all of them as part of your TDD process.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense, however, would you take the approach of keeping them in the same test file and just separate them by region (in .net), or would you create a separate folder (or even project), for unit/integration/UI tests?

Comment: I prefer the rails convention of a test or spec directory containing sub directories for each type of test which in turn contain a file per class or aspect tested. E.g. 'specs/models/foo' or 'tests/integration/bar'.

Answer (score 2):

The line between integration tests and unit tests can be be a bit fuzzy; it's worthwhile, while doing TDD, to test "up" to an integration level, just to get confirmation of functionality, but it's certainly overkill during TDD to put in place "comprehensive" integration tests (note the quotes around comprehensive there).

Basically, there's a significant aspect of "judgment call" going on; your experience should be a good guide as to the appropriate level to stop adding tests during TDD mode.

Comment: So basically it's kind of like, I tested a broad enough scenario here, let's get broader later on and just focus on adding more functionality while doing TDD sorta thing?

Comment: @slandau: yeah, that's roughly it; the point is not to get bogged down in the details of overly-rigorous testing during the TDD process; remember that it's a development process first and foremost.  Remember that no code, even TDD code, is bug-free; it's a balance between code quality and productivity.